# Horizontal and Vertical Scrolling Usign UICollectionView and ScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have an app in which There is a `Card View`.

I have put the card in `UICollectionViewCell`.

My Flow layout is `Horizontal`.

Cards was scrolling `Horizontaly`.

Now the problem rises when I have to support `iPhone4s`.

The Vertical Length of Card is Very long to fit in Screen.So I have to Scroll the Content in `UICollectionView` Vertically also.

So I Decided to put my `UICollectionView` inside `UIScrollView`.
[image]

In my `viewDidLoad` I am setting the content size of `UIScrollView`.

But it is not scrolling.

What I am missing.??

Comment: your touches are intercepted by the collectionview which itself is a scrollview.If the colleciton view covers the scrollview, there is no use of creating a scroll view and adding a collectinview to it. Instead you could reduce the cell size to fit the device screen!

Comment: @TejaNandamuri Hi ... I can't reduce the size of Cell size..as It contains text data and some images....By AutoLayout its already shorted based on screen size...I have to scroll it vertically, is their any other way of doing it?

Comment: are you using autolayout ?

Comment: @Shubhank Yes I am using Autolauout

Comment: then setting contentSize wont work, you need to add proper constraints to make it scroll

Comment: @Shubhank Now I have changed my settings...Now I have `CollectionView-CollectionVIewCell-ScrollView-View-Content` but my ScrollView isn't scrolling

Answer (score 0):

you can have tableview and then add collection view in tableview cell and thus you can have horizontal as well as vertical scrolling without any interruption.
 **UITableView->UITableViewCell->UICollectionView in tableview cell->load cells in collectionview**

Comment: If I do this then things will become more complex. I have to manage delegate of both TableView and CollectionView.  I have acheived this by doing this. : `CollectionView-CollectionVIewCell-ScrollView-View-Content` and thnks for your suggestion  @Diksha.

Comment: yes may be but the you have also written the code for tableView...In my approach I don't have to write a single line of code :)

Comment: but yes your approach is also good. even this approach not strikes in my mind